# Azure Event Grid triggers Azure Function App multiple times instead of once

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

Here is the structure, a data-drift-detected event in ML Workspace sends the event into event grid which triggers a function in Azure Function App. I want it to run only once after the data drift detection. However, I got this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsR47.png)

It runs every ~20s for a few times ://

Here is my host.json:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

and function.json:

```json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
            "type": "eventGridTrigger",
            "name": "event",
            "direction": "in"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried changing default options in "singleton" field in host.json, but nothing changed.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an event grid trigger there you will have retry policies where you can change it 1.

[image]

Event grid trigger waits of response if it doesnt get it triggers again until it gets a response, so change it to 1. To only trigger once.
So if event grid doesnt get response it triggers again with some interval of time

If not you are sending responses, so its triggering try not to send more responses to your end point.

**References taken from:**

- [Azure Event Grid delivery and retry - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule)